# VS2010: Setting Up File Details on Application Build

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After I right-click on a file in Windows (ex: Windows 7 64bit), a pop-up menu appears with *"Properties"* on its bottom.

Going to: **Mouse-Right-Click on a File -> Properties -> Details** I get a tab with file description containing:

- File Description
- Type
- File Version
- Product Version
- Copyright
- Size
- Date modified
- Language

Is it possible to setup any of the above parameters (Example: *File Version, Product Version, Copyright*) from within **Visual Studio 2010**? I want to have the parameters available after each compile/build session.

If yes, how to do that? If not, what is the appropriate way of setting them up? I did not find anything relevant on internet yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual C++ project add a resource file with version information. See MSDN help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Hi, Gene, manwhile, I found the same way. Thank you for help. I accessed the Version resource with GetFileVersionInfo(). Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I am currently using VS2015, to our project contained additional information, follow these steps:

1. In Solution Explorer select project and then: mouse-right-click on a Project -> Add -> New Item.
2. Then on the left side in the new window, select: Installed -> Visual C ++ -> Resource.
3. Choose Resource File (rc). Enter the name for example Version.
4. When you see the Resource View on the previously entered name file, right click mouse and from the context menu select Add resource.
5. With resource type select Version and then click in the New button.

Fill the data and rebuild the project. Done.

Comment: It still works with VS2022 with precise instructions

Answer (score 1):

Update you assembly file based on the executable or class library you are building.  I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("My Product Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("My Product Description")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("My Product Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © My Company 2010")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Hi, dretlaff17, thanks for the reply. I searched the internet for the "Assembly files". I did nto get explanation on what an assembly file is, and where to find it in the VS. Meanwhile, I added "Version" resources, to my project, and accessed it via GetFileVersionInfo().

Comment: The question is about native C++ libraries and not .NET assemblies. The metadata description you listed are C#-specific assembly attributes. In C++ there are resource files (`.rc`), containing file information.

Comment: It is for C# not C++ as mentioned in question