# Setting Windows File details for built exe in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I am creating an exe using MinGW as the compiler.
I want to have the file details for my exe.
A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070360/vs2010-setting-up-file-details-on-application-build), however it works for MSVC only.
I have even tried adding the following code in the .rc file. Incidentally the same .rc file has some code for taking the icon file, which is working fine!

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "000004b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "\0"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "MyApp Description\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1\0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Test\0"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © 2013\0"
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks", "\0"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "OriginalFilename\0"
            VALUE "PrivateBuild", "\0"
            VALUE "ProductName", "MyApp\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1\0"
            VALUE "SpecialBuild", "\0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0, 1200
    END
END
```

Still I am not getting any of the details in the built exe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you building the resource file? Keep in mind that (see [MS resource compiler](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MS_resource_compiler)):

> The main difference between using the MS resource tools and the GNU
>   tools is that MS rc generates a ".res" file in a special binary
>   resource format, which can be passed directly to MS link, while the
>   GNU linker ld only supports resources in ".o" (same as ".obj") format
>   (although windres can output in both formats).

Example:

```
windres -o resfile.o demo.rc
gcc -o demo demo.o resfile.o -mwindows
```

Here is an example [Adding Version Information and Comments to your DLL](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/).

Comment: Hi Marius, actually I am using Qt, which uses qmake.exe for building. It uses a .pro file which contains the names of all the source, header, ui, resource files.
This is my build config: qmake.exe C:\path\to\myApp.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=release"

Comment: added #include <windows.h> & works just fine. :)
Somehow the reference I was using did not mention adding windows.h in the resource file... Anyways thanks for both the links